# Flattening the recursion in QuickSort

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

So I'm trying to implement QuickSort in Python 2.7 and I have done so successfully with a recursive function, but it is understandably getting upset when I call quicksort(range(1000)[::-1]).  That is to say it maxes out the recursion depth allowed in Python.

So now I want to "flatten" this function, that is to say, use as few as possible (or no) recursive calls.  I've been trying to implement this by having a partition function that doesn't return the list but only returns the position of the pivot after sorting everything to the left and right.  I've written this and tested it, it seems to work perfectly.  If anyone's interested, though, the code is below.

The trick now seems to be to get this thing to partition repeatedly until the whole list is sorted, and I'm struggling to see how to make that part happen.  One thought I have is to create an ordered list of indices which are all the indices which have been used for a pivot.  Then I could run a while loop that would break when the list of indices is the same as range(n).  I'm not sure how smart or elegant this idea is though, since I'd be producing a second list of the same length as the input list--seems kind of like an avoidable memory hog.  On the other hand it seems like you need a method of keeping track of which segments of the list you've already sorted, and for that I can only think of recursion or this list idea.

So the question is, is the list idea good or bad, and if bad, what is a better idea?

```
def partition(x, start, end, pivotIndex):
    '''
    x is a list, start to end is the portion of the list to sort, and 
    pivotIndex is the index at which pull a value and sort everything above
    and below this.
    '''
    low = start # Low will track the lower bound of the position in the list
                # where "small" elements get switched into.  It starts at 
                # start.
    high = end-1
    p = x[pivotIndex] # Pivot value
    x[pivotIndex] = x[end] # We basically move the pivot entry out of the way
                           # and we'll put it back in at the end.
    while True:
        while low <= high and x[low] < p: # We cycle up the bottom of the list
                          # until we've looked at everything or until we hit
                          # a pice that's out of place.
            low += 1
        while low <= high and x[high] >= p: # And do likewise from the top of 
                         # the list.
            high -= 1
        if low > high: # If we've covered the whole list, the partition is 
                       # done.  Otherwise, there must be pieces out of place
                       # so swap them.
            break
        x[low], x[high] = x[high], x[low]
    x[end] = x[low] # The value at end stores a duplicate of some value,
                    # since we copied it in, so now we want to over-ride that.
                    # We choose to put the element now at low there, and put
                    # since the pivot value was taken out of the list, we now
                    # put it in the low position.
    x[low] = p
    return low
```

Comment: What is the question? Can you make sure that the question is highlighted?

Comment: There are many examples of [iterative quick sort](https://www.google.com/search?q=iterative+quick+sort) implementations, it sounds like "iterative" is the word you're looking for, not "flatten".

Comment: Typically the way to "flatten" recursion is to use a stack (first-in last-out) data structure.

Comment: You need a stack to store the partition indices.  I have never heard of a version of quicksort with O(1) space complexity and O(log n) time complexity.  If you quicksort the smaller of the two partitions first, then you get guaranteed O(log n) space complexity.  However, you still need an explicit stack.

Comment: NOt really answering your question but ... how are you choosing the pivot in the recursive solution? Either a random pivot or median-of-three will generally survive even the pathological case.Which means an average of O(log n) recusions - a max depth of 10 for your example. If using a random pivot you can always catch the max-depth exception and retry a few times